# After UV unwrapping > Shading > Add image Texture > Object show no image texture

Tags: rendering, materials, uv, eevee-render-engine, uv-image-editor

Blender 2.93.6/Windows 10

I am following a demo. I added a material brown color to my landscape which is showing fine. Then I selected my object and UV > Unwrap. Then change to shading > Add texture Image. The Texture image is not showing in either Material Preview or Render. It does show the brown color though.

I tried :
Using Unwrap and Project from view  > Same result
Changing Render from Eevee to Cycles to Workbench > Same result.

[image]

Here is the UV Editing view
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated
(Happy New Year!!)

Comment: Beginners issue. I had the "Use Nodes" disabled. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

plug in a mapping node and a coordinates node set to UV. make sure your texture scale is not to large or to small in de mapping node.